# Closure of $X=\{x:d(x,a)<r\}$ is $\bar{X}=\{x:d(x,a)\leq r\}$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

True or False: Can somebody comment on my line of thought?

> Closure of $X:=\{x:d(x,a)<r\}$ is always $\bar X:=\{x:d(x,a)\leq r\}$

**True:**

Suppose for a contradiction it's not. Then we can find a smaller closed set, call it $X_1$ such that $X\in X_1$. Thus we can exclude some point $x_1$ from $\bar X$. Since $X_1$ is closed we can find and open ball: $B_\epsilon (x_1)$ such that $B_\epsilon (x_1) \notin X_1$.

Thus we can find another point $x_2$ such that $x_2 \in B_\epsilon (x_1) \notin X_1$ and also $x_2 \in X$. Thus this is a contradiction, since we assumed $X\in X_1$

> Is this correct? I was trying to actually pinpoint $x_2$ by using the
>   radius but I couldn't figure it out

Comment: Sorry, it is false.

Comment: @egreg Is it to do with different metrics? I assumed to be working on the euclidian metric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it's false.

Consider a non empty set $A$ with the discrete metric
$$
d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x=y$}\\
1 & \text{if $x\ne y$}
\end{cases}
$$
Then the closure of $\{x:d(a,x)<1\}$ is $\{a\}$, whereas $\{x:d(a,x)\le 1\}=A$. As soon as $A$ has more than one element, you're doomed.

If your space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric, then it's true.

It is not restrictive to assume $a=0$, which makes things simpler.

The set $\{x:d(0,x)\le r\}$ is obviously closed, so it contains $\bar{X}$. Suppose $d(0,b)=r$ and consider the segment joining $0$ to $b$, which can be seen as the arc $t\mapsto tb$, for $t\in[0,1]$. Now, find a sequence in $X$ converging to $b$.

Hint: $x_n=r(1-1/n)b$

Note that this can be again false if your space is a *subset* of a Euclidean space with the Euclidean metric. For instance, in the subset $(0,1]\cup\{2\}$, we have
$$
\{x:d(1,x)<1\}=(0,1]
$$
which is (relatively) closed, but
$$
\{x:d(1,x)\le1\}=(0,1]\cup\{2\}
$$

Comment: Thanks, so is my proof correct for euclidean metric :)?

Comment: @GRS Sorry, no. It's not correct. At the least, you are confusing $\subset$ with $\in$.

Comment: As in your  example, in general we may have B(x,r)=B(x,s) with different r,s.

Comment: @user254665 Yes, certainly so. Consider $(0,1]\cup[2,3)$ and $r=1$; the set $\{x:d(1,x)<1\}$ is closed, but $\{x:d(1,x)\le 1\}$ also contains $2$.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't the set $x:d(1,x)<1$ be neither open nor closed? Since we are on $(0,1]$

Comment: @GRS It is closed without any doubt. Remember the space is *just* $(0,1]\cup\{2\}$: there's nothing else.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I see that since it covers the whole space and the whole space is closed, so it's closed. Also this means that the set containing the whole space minus finitely many points is also closed?

Comment: @GRS No: in this space, $2$ is an isolated point, so $\{2\}$ is (relatively) open and its complement is closed (as well as open, in this case). In general, if you take away from a metric space a finite number of points, you get an open set.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the discrete metric, another interesting example is the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$, in which the balls $\{x:|x-a|<r\}$ are both open and closed.